# How to cancel the thread immediately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I use NSThread to create a new thread, then it is executing the thread_funtion, I want to cancel the thread, I use [thread cancel], but the thread will go on.

```
NSThread *thread=[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread_funtion) object:nil];
[thread start];

-(void)thread_funtion
{
     //my code
}
```

I know in the thread_funtion use flag to control its execute,it can be useful,but it is too complex.

```
-(void)thread_funtion
{
      if(flag)
    {
        //some code
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

So question 1: How to cancel the thread immediately？

Then I use another method to create a new thread:

```
pthread_t id;
int ret;
ret=pthread_create(&id,NULL,thread_function,NULL);
if(ret!=0){
    printf ("Create pthread error!\n");
    exit (1);
}
```

Then I use pthread_cancel(id), the thread will stop immediately.
But in the thread_function:

```
void* thread_function(void *arg)
{
    //This is not a function of the class, So I can't use self.somobject !
}
```

So the question is ,int the c code,how to use the object of the class?

Comment: How about `-[NSThread exit]`?

Comment: @CodaFi I try it，but doesn't work. Thx all the same.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to be using an NSThread, you should probably be using GCD or NSOperations for multithreaded work. Much more performant and easier to work with. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

Answer (score 3):

`NSThread` cancellation simply sets a flag in the thread which it can discover by calling `isCancelled`. It does *not* stop the thread if the thread is intent on continuing.

And this is actually a *good* thing. From my long experience in multi-threading, I'm of the opinion that theads should be in total control of themselves, *including their own lifetimes.*

Killing threads when they have locks on resources or while they're halfway through updating critical structures is not a good idea.

It would be a good idea to re-architect your thread functions so that they periodically call `isCancelled` and act upon that. If you do it right, you can guarantee a maximum latency for response to cancellation by checking at certain points, checking within loops, ensuring any blocking calls have timeouts or ways to unblock them, and so on.